# Rufus-Scheduler permission denied error when setting rufus-scheduler.lock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, digital-ocean, rufus-scheduler

I'm trying to setup a lock on rufus-scheduler to prevent my scheduled tasks from running multiple time. When I deploy this to production I receive the following error:

> nginx_error.log — Message from application: Permission denied @
>   rb_sysopen - .rufus-scheduler.lock (Errno::EACCES)

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.2 and Rails 4.2 on Digital Ocean. This runs fine without the lock but all the scheduled tasks run twice. Here's the code with the lock added that is triggering the permission problem:

```
SCHEDULER = Rufus::Scheduler.new(:lockfile => ".rufus-scheduler.lock")
```

This environment was setup automatically using Cloud66.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that the user under which your Ruby interpreter is running doesn't have the right to write `{current_directory}/.rufus-scheduler.lock`

**solution a**

You could make sure your process user may write in the current directory.

**solution b**

You could point to directory where any user can write.

```
SCHEDULER = Rufus::Scheduler.new(lockfile: "/tmp/.rufus-scheduler.lock")
```

**solution c**

Use something else than Cloud66, it seems the user they're giving you can't write.

Comment: I tried solution b but it led to the same problem: 

nginx_error.log — Message from application: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /tmp/.rufus-scheduler.lock (Errno::EACCES)

Comment: Then you have to give your user more rights, or run your Ruby process with a user that has more rights. You should update the question and indicate how you installed (which Digital Ocean guide you followed), else it will be difficult to help you